# Python Assistance Searching a List

Tags: python, database, list, indexing

```
"""read file and store into database"""
f = open('C:\\Users\\user.name\\Desktop\\tunes.txt','r')
artist=[""]
song=[""]
album=[""]
genre=[""]
index=0
for line in f:
    if index==0:
        artist.append(line)
        index=index+1
    elif index==1:
        song.append(line)
        index=index+1
    elif index==2:
        album.append(line)
        index=index+1
    elif index==3:
        genre.append(line)
        index=index+1
    elif index==4:
        index=0   
while 1:
    selection = int(raw_input("Please select the number that corresponds with what you would like to do.\n1.Search\n2.Recommend\n3.Edit\n4.Save\n"))
    if selection == 1:
        print "You selected Search"
        searchselection = int(raw_input("Please select the number that corresponds with what you would like to do.\n1.Display All Songs\n2.Display All Artists\n3.Search By Artist\n4.Display All Genres\n5.Search by Genre\n6.Display All Playlists\n7.Search By Playlist\n"))                               
        if searchselection == 1:
           print '[%s]' % ''.join(map(str, song))
        elif searchselection == 2:
            print '[%s]' % ''.join(map(str, artist))
        elif searchselection == 3:
            artistsearch = str(raw_input("\nWhat artist are you searching for?\n"))
            artist.index(artistsearch)
            print value
        elif searchselection == 4:
            print '[%s]' % ''.join(map(str, genre))
        elif searchselection == 5:
            print "display"
        elif searchselection == 6:
            print "display"
        elif searchselection == 7:
            print "display"
        break
    elif selection == 2:
        print "You selected recommend."
        recommendselection = int(raw_input("Please select the number that corresponds with what you would like to do.\n1.Recommend by Song Title\n2.Recommend by Artist Name\n"))
        if recommendselection == 1:
            songrec = str(raw_input("Please enter the song title\n"))

        elif recommendselection == 2:
            artistrec = str(raw_input("Please enter the Artist's name\n"))
        break
    elif selection == 3:
        print "You selected edit."
        editselection = int(raw_input("Please select the number that corresponds with what you would like to do.\n1.Add a New Song\n2.Create New Playlist\n3.Add a song to a current playlist"))
        if editselection == 1:
            songadd = str(raw_input("Please enter the EVERYTHING\n"))
        elif editselection == 2:
            playistcreate = str(raw_input("Please enter the name of the Playlist\n"))
        elif editselection == 3:
            playlistadd = str(raw_input("Please enter the name of the playlist\n"))      
        break
    elif selection == 4:
        print "You selected Save."
        f.close()
        break
```

So that is what I have thus far. This is an ongoing python project, and right now I am stumped; I am trying to search by artist like if Justin Timberlake is typed in by the user as "artistsearch" then I want the index to be pulled so that I can match the index in the song list and display that information to the user.

Any help determining why Justin Timberlake is not a value on the list even though the name shows up when I run the display all artists option would be greatly appreciated.

Also being pointed in the right direction for matching list indexes would be great as well. This is an example of the tunes.txt:

```
Alicia Keys
No One
As I Am
R&B/Soul;Syl tunes

Everything But the Girl
Missing
Amplified Heart
Alternative;Syl tunes

Gathering Field
Lost In America
Lost In America
Rock

Ellie Goulding
Burn
Halcyon
Pop;Road tunes

Justin Timberlake
Mirrors
Mirrors (Radio Edit) - Single
Pop;Syl tunes
```

Comment: It doesn't sound like a `list` is an appropriate data structure. This would be greatly simplified with a dictionary/nested dictionaries.

Comment: You may be right, but I've allready come this far, and wonder how much back tracking and research I'll need to do to implement the dictionary data structure.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technical_debt

Comment: Parsing the above `.txt` file into a nested dictionary structure should be relatively easy. Probably 5-10 lines of code being verbose about it...

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create a specific class for the data you want to store, and then create a list of objects that instantiate such class:

```
class Song():
    """Class to store the attributes for each song"""
    def __init__ (self):
        self.artist = ""
        self.song = ""
        self.album = ""
        self.genre = ""

# List to store all the Song objects
songs_list = []

f = open('C:\\Users\\user.name\\Desktop\\tunes.txt','r')
index=0
for line in f:
    # Instantiate an empty Song object
    s = Song()
    if index == 0:
        s.artist = line
        index=index+1
    elif index == 1:
        s.song = line
        index = index + 1
    elif index == 2:
        s.album = line
        index = index + 1
    elif index == 3:
        s.genre = line
        index = index+1
    elif index == 4:
        index = 0
    songs_list.append(s)
```